# asMap-implementation for Java (based on Arrays.asList)

Tags: java

I am always tired of the very verbose syntax in Java for creating small maps. [`Arrays.asList(T... a)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) is very convenient, and therefore I want something similar for a map.

```
public class MapUtils {
    public static <K, V> MapBuilder<K, V> asMap(K key, V value) {
        return new MapBuilder<K, V>().entry(key, value);
    }

    public static class MapBuilder<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V> {
        public MapBuilder<K, V> entry(K key, V value) {
            this.put(key, value);
            return this;
        }
    }
}

/* Example of how to use asMap */
public class Example {
    public void example() {
        Map<String, String> map = MapUtil.asMap("key", "value").entry("key2", "value2");
    }
}

/* Example of how the one way to create an inline Map in Java */
public class Before {
    public void before() {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
            put("key", value");
            put("key2", value2");
        }};
    }
}
```

Any inputs on how to improve this implementation of `MapUtils`? Do you consider the `asMap` function a good idea, or am I too lazy to write some extra characters?

Comment: Looks nice to me. But Landeis solution seems reasonable. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my opinion `MapBuilder` should *contain* a `Map`, not extend one. Another possible design would be to use a single call with varargs:

```
public class MapUtil {
    public static <K,V> Map<K,V> asMap(Map.Entry<K,V>... entries) {
        Map<K,V> map = new HashMap<K,V>();
        for(Map.Entry<K,V> entry : entries) {
            map.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        return map;
    }

    public static <K,V> Map.Entry<K,V> e(final K k, final V v) {
        return new Map.Entry<K, V>() {
            public K getKey() {
                return k;
            }
            public V getValue() {
                return v;
            }
            public V setValue(V value) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported");
            }
        };
    }
} 

import static very.useful.MapUtil.*;
... 
Map<String, Integer> map = asMap(e("x",1),e("y",2),e("z",3));
```

Comment: Well, well, but `e`? Just `e`? A bit aggressive and cryptic.

Comment: I used `e` for "entry", but of course this is a matter of taste. The best thing would be an operator as in Scala (here `->`), but the only symbolic things we have for Java names are `$` and `_`. Hmmm, maybe we should use `$$` for pairs, that would make at least a little bit sense.

Comment: Well, or maybe `entry` for entry? :)

Comment: @user unknown: IMHO that would be too long.

Comment: I don't like the `e`-function either, but I guess it is a necessary evil.

Answer (score 5):

google-collections has all about it, e.g. [ImmutableMap.of()](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html#of%28K,%20V,%20K,%20V%29).
Moreover they teach using right data structure, like **true** immutable collections, ordered lists etc. I really enjoyed it.

---

Google Collections is now part of Google Guava, and it includes [ImmutableMap.Builder](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.Builder.html). With this you can do:

```
   static final ImmutableMap<String, Integer> WORD_TO_INT =
   new ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Integer>()
       .put("one", 1)
       .put("two", 2)
       .put("three", 3)
       .build();
```

You can call the `put(K, V)` method as many times as you like. Builders are great for this kind of situation.

Comment: Nice tip with google-collections. But it only supports up to five entries.

Comment: I have edited this answer with an example of using ImmutableMap.Builder, which gets around the 5 entries limit. I'm waiting for it to be peer reviewed.

Answer (score 1):

I like Landei version, but I have also an untyped version of asMap like asMap(key,value,key,value,...). It is not typed Map, but in many cases, it fits the bill pretty well.

So

```
Map quickMap = asMap("prop1","val1","prop2",12,"prop3");
```

In this case "prop3" will have a value null.

Implementation:

```
static final public Map<String, Object> asMap(Object... objs) {
    HashMap<String, Object> m = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    for (int i = 0; i < objs.length; i += 2) {
        String key = objs[i].toString();
        if (i + 1 < objs.length) {
            Object value = objs[i + 1];
            m.put(key, value);
        } else {
            m.put(key, null);
        }
    }
    return m;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this. Only the last value can contain null this way.

Comment: @yuri  I am not sure, because a asMap("prop1",null,"prop2",12,"prop3"); should work, no?

Comment: sure, but it is inconsistent, which means that if you get an odd list of objects, chances are the programmer made a mistake. So I would at least implement a check on `%2==0` for the argument list. And you always return something of type `Map<String, Object>`, maybe make a templated version?